# Reading the cookie in Angular 7

Tags: angular, cookies, session-cookies

I have an angular 7 application

**www.myapp1.com**

i have another application for login authentication.

**www.myauthapp.com**

When ever i send login request my **myauthapp** will process request and saves some details in cookie. So my doubt is how can i read these cookie from my angular application **myapp1**

i have tried so many examples from google [here it is link](https://tutorialedge.net/typescript/angular/angular-cookies-tutorial/).

Comment: When you tried the approach, what error you were getting?

Comment: You can access the cookies with plain js like `allCookies = document.cookie;`. Check out the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or this [post on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript),

Comment: @riorudo This is in java script. How can i get it in Typescript in angular 7

Comment: @Pranav MS if you take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/salemdar/angular2-cookie/blob/master/src/services/cookies.service.ts) of the example you posted, a similar method with plain js was used within the cookieService.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that is not possible for accessing cookie of different site.
You should set cookie from myapp1 and then only access via myapp1.

Or use localstorage too.